# How to unescape non-usa, en, ASCII type characters using grep?

Tags: java, unicode, escaping, grep, facebook-graph-api

I am using grep to parse a friend list obtained via the facebook Open Graph API. I am mostly able to do what I want with the following command, issued in bash:

```
grep -aiPo '"name":"(.*?)","id":"[[:digit:]]*"' friends?blahblah-access-token-stuff
```

which yields a list which looks like:

```
"name":"John Day","id":"--id ommitted--"
"name":"Andria Cast\u00f1eda","id":"--id ommitted--" // let me draw your attention here
"name":"Jane Doe","id":"--id ommitted--"
```

*Names were changed above to preserve privacy*

If you notice, there is an unescaped sequence in the middle entry, that corresponds to a tilde N. Is there an easy way to to feed such characters into a java program (my primary intention) so that java understands that \u00f1eda is unicode speak for the curly n?

I would **prefer not** to solve this problem by parsing the string in java and manually unescaping the unicode. I would very much prefer to instruct grep to handle this situation, or another GNU or open source tool that is widely available for bash.

At that point, I would feed the entire input as a file to a java program without having to worry about OMG, is that a unicode escape sequence!!? Java would naturally detect the unicode characters and map them to it's corresponding internal representation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Andria Cast\u00f1eda" is the way Unicode would be escaped in Java anyway. So it should output the correct character. I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Ok, if I call System.out.println('\u00f1eda'), it will print the correct unicode character. However, will I be able to do typical string operations? Like, compare "Andria Cast\u00f1eda" to "Bob Joel"?

Comment: In exactly the same way as normal. Java will treat the escaped Unicode as a single character, so all normal string manipulation and comparison applies, you don't have to do anything special. Just don't do any byte by byte comparisons, use the convenience String methods.

Comment: Do Perl and/or Python qualify as widely available tools? There are easy solutions with both.

Comment: @Apalala: The point is he doesn't need an additional solution, Java will handle an escaped string the same as an unescaped string. See my answer below.

Comment: @Mikaveli Java has to be compiled, and it is not clear from the requirements if the strings can be embedded in the target program, or if they have to be read as imput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java understands Unicode. You provide Java Unicode escapes in the following manner:

```
String str = "\u00F6";
```

So if you pass a string such as `"Andria Cast\u00f1eda"` which *is* an escaped sequence, it should be handled correctly without any additional handling required.

Here's also a very brief, but easy to understand introduction:

[Unicode in Java](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/unicode_in_java.html)

If you're still not convinced, try this class:

```
public class UnicodeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String escaped = new String("\u00f1");
        String unescaped = new String("ñ");
        System.out.println(escaped);        
        System.out.println(unescaped);
        
        if(escaped.equals(unescaped)){
            System.out.println("The strings are the same!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The strings are different!");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is impossible as the bytewise datastream used by grep cannot encode all unicode characeters.

Comment: Would it be possible to feed the output from grep to another program that would be capable of doing this type of manipulation?

Comment: It would be, but the next program in the pipeline afterwords needs to support unicode on its input stream.